# When to remove USB stick after install?

Tags: installation, usb

Just installed 13.04 from USB stick, it said needed to restart to complete, but just rebooted to the gnu grub screen.. No new options, just try Ubuntu, install it, or check disc for errors.. Tried again and took the USB stick out right after I clicked restart and it froze.. It won't load without the stick in.. Tried this install three times now..

Answer (score 2):

1. Shut down your computer.
2. Remove your USB stick.
3. Now start your computer.
   I hope this will work for you.

Comment: Says image not found in a blue box black screen..

Comment: Did the installation complete?

Comment: Yes, the restart screen came up, and when clicked on it, rebooted to the gnu grub screen with the same options as pre install

Comment: Can you upload a picture of the screen?

Answer (score 2):

Boot with the USB stick in, and open terminal.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

You will see something like that image below. look for the device with the boor flag.  In the example its `/dev/sda1`.

[image]

You case might be different.  Once you find out your boot device, just do

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdxx
```

Replace the xx with your device ID.  Once done, shut down the machine and remove your USB device.

Comment: That should address the issues I described ..

Answer (score 0):

On some older PCs, removing the USB device (containing USB startup/installer) remaps the existing devices.

This leaves the GRUB target (to install Ubuntu from) invalid. *I haven't seen this is a couple of years, it mainly affected me on **10.04 LTS**.*

---

You need to run **`update-grub`**, without the USB stick being present. There were a couple of techniques, like booting (with stick) and then running **update-grub** from Ubuntu (after stick removed). This was always temperamental ..*

The other approach was using the USB-stick to get to recovery mode, but that worked best with the (older) Alternative installer (as opposed to Desktop or Server) with its additional tools, drivers, and utilities.

***Anyone seen this issue with 12.04 LTS or 13.04 ?***